# Angular show error when I try to ng add angular/fire@next

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angularfire

Showing error whenever I try to add

```
ng add angular/fire@next
```

using CLI

> Compiling @angular/fire : main as umd
>
> Compiling @angular/fire : module as esm5
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/auth : es2015 as esm2015
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/auth : main as umd
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/auth : module as esm5
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/auth-guard : es2015 as esm2015
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/auth-guard : main as umd
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/auth-guard : module as esm5
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/database : es2015 as esm2015
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/database : main as umd
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/database : module as esm5
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/database-deprecated : es2015 as esm2015
>
> Compiling @angular/fire/database-deprecated : main as umd
>
> Error: Tried to overwrite E:/portfolio/node_modules/@angular/fire/bundles/database.umd.js.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed.
>       at InPlaceFileWriter.writeFileAndBackup (E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\writing\in_place_file_writer.js:36:23)
>       at E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\writing\in_place_file_writer.js:30:69
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at InPlaceFileWriter.writeBundle (E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\writing\in_place_file_writer.js:30:30)
>       at E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:103:36
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object.mainNgcc (E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:75:21)
>       at E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\main-ngcc.js:67:20
>       at Object.defineProperty.value (E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\main-ngcc.js:4:17)
>       at Object. (E:\portfolio\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\main-ngcc.js:10:3)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! portfolio@0.0.0 postinstall: `ivy-ngcc`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.0.0 postinstall script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bhautik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-20T13_49_06_035Z-debug.log
>
> Package install failed, see above.

Here is my angular version

```
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.1.0-beta.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.1
@angular/cli                      8.0.1
@angular/fire                     5.2.0-rc.3
@angular/pwa                      0.800.3
@angular/service-worker           8.1.0-next.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.1
@schematics/angular               8.0.1
@schematics/update                0.800.1
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

Comment: It seems like you running with Ivy opt-in. Can you confirm? Check your tsconfig.app.json file if the `angularComplierOption` has an `enableIvy` prop which is sets to true.

Comment: Yes, It already set to true